# substitute a value according to specific condition in R

Tags: r, division

i have a df structured like this:

```
 Value.  Numb. 
   46.   200
   47.   200
   55.   200
   21.   200
   32.   140
   23.   140
   56.   700
```

If numb value is repeated, I want to substitute the value with the result of the division *Numb/number of times it appears*, obtaining a new df:

```
 Value.  Numb. 
   46.    50
   47.    50
   55.    50
   21.    50
   32.    70
   23.    70
   56.   700
```

How can I do? better a solution comprising the use of dplyr.

Comment: number of times it appears overall in `Numb` column or consecutive number of times it appear ?

Comment: overall in numb column!

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Numb.) %>% mutate(Number=Numb./n()) %>% ungroup()
```

Answer (score 1):

One way using `ave` is to create a grouping variable `Numb` and calculate the `length` of each group and divide the `Numb` by the `length`.

```
with(df, Numb/ave(Numb, Numb, FUN = length))
#[1]  50  50  50  50  70  70 700
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is `data.table`.  Grouped by 'Numb.', divide the column by the number of rows

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Numb. := Numb./.N, Numb.]
```